# Aumentar timeout de uma página

Tags: php

eu tenho rodado uns testes, e eles demoram um pouco pra retornar o resultado, porém no meu domínio, ele tem dado timeout quando alcança 30segs. Eu sei que vai gerar um resultado, só vai demorar mais algum momento. É possível aumentar o timeout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode aumentar o timeout da seguinte forma:

```
set_time_limit(120);//coloque no inicio do arquivo
```

Você pode deixar sem timeout (irá funcionar indefinidamente (se o php estiver em safe mode isso não irá funcionar))

```
set_time_limit(0);//coloque no inicio do arquivo
```

Pode-se mudar através do php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 120
```

Caso não tenha acesso ao php.ini

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 120);
```

(todos os valores são segundos)

Answer (score 1):

Faça assim:

```
$segundos = 0;
set_time_limit($segundos);
```