# Wordpress não consigo baixar plugin UpdraftPlus

Tags: mysql, wordpress, plugin

*Eu estava baixando os plugins do wordpress mas quando fui baixar o UpdraftPlus deu o sequinte erro:*

https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/updraftplus.1.16.23.zip…

Descompactando o pacote…

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-admin\includes\class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 81
Há um erro crítico no seu site. Verifique seu e-mail para instruções.>

**Eu olhei o email mas não chegou, alquem sabe qual o problema ?**

Comment: Pelo Wordpress diretamente não sei se é possivel fazer, mas pelo php.ini no Xampp você pode aumentar o tempo setando `max_execution_time`, talvez 360 segundos ou mais `max_execution_time = 360`

Comment: Isto resolve o seu problema: [Aumentar timeout de uma página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/74738/aumentar-timeout-de-uma-p%c3%a1gina)

Answer (score -3):

Baixa direto pelo navegador, de forma normal, depois sobe para o local que você necessita. 
Se ainda assim não conseguir, tente também usando uma VPN. E em último caso, reinicie seu modem.

Abraços

Comment: vlw cara vou tentar

Comment: Depois me diga se conseguiu resolver, e encerre o caso, caso tenha conseguido.

Comment: consequi sim vlw